# Why is this on hold?

Tags: discussion

[Ninety-ninety rule in practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/337749/198652)

So, I don't think that this question is too broad, and it got closed. I'm wondering why is that so, and what should I do to get this question reopened.

Comment: Just wait, I see already 3 votes for reopening it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has been reopened.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! :)